# Is there any option to adjust dynamically height of absolute positioned child to his relative parent?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have problem with keeping my child div the same height of parent during shrinking browser window(checking responsive mode). What i would like to achieve is to not allow the content inside absolute positioned child overflow but at the same time would like to keep the size of child div on 100% height of the parent div.I know that absolute position causes element to interfere natural page positioning, but maybe you know some tricks or JS is only way?
Regards!

HTML code:

```
<div class=parent>
<div class=child>
<p class=intro>Introduction</p>
<div class=box_container>
  <div class=box></div>
  <p>some_text</p>
 </div>
 <div class=box_container>
  <div class=box></div>
  <p>some_text</p>
 </div>
 <div class=box_container>
  <div class=box></div>
  <p>some_text</p>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.parent{

  width:250px;
  height:250px;
  background-color:green;
  position:relative;
}

.child{
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;

background-color:red;
position:absolute;

}
.box_container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  align-items:center;

}
.intro{
  position:relative;
   top:10px
}

.box{
  width:15px;
  height:15px;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

Link to fiddlejs with code: https://jsfiddle.net/bfbcfu2e/1/

Comment: just add `height:100%` to `.child`

Comment: If i do it then content from child div will overflow because of shrinking;/

Answer (score 0):

You can add:

```
top:0;
bottom:0;
```

...to an absolutely-positioned element and it will fit the height of its *positioned* container.  But if there's not enough space for the text content, it will struggle to fit everything inside for you.